# Can I upload a new build after Apple's app review or Google's app review is done?

Tags: android, ios, maui

I am upgrading Native app to .NET MAUI.

My current app is using Java(Android) and Swift(iOS) with build version v1.0.0.

I will submit a build version 2.0.0(.NET MAUI) for reviewing by Apple or Google.

when that build version is approved by Apple or Google. The state of this build is 'pending developer release'.

Then I want to submit another build version 2.1.0 (Java,Swift) for reviewing again and will get approved.

Hence, I have 2 build versions approved by GG or Apple. One is .NET MAUI app and the other is Native app.

Then i publish MAUI app to GG play or Apple store.

I want to ensure that if build version 2.0.0(.NET MAUI) has errors, I will publish v2.1.0(Java,Swift) immediately.

Is it possible to upload a new build version after previous review get approved by Apple or Google but didn't publish to market?

In other words, Does GG or Apple allow to store 2 ready versions for publishing?

Comment: AFAIK, on the AppStore, you can upload a new build to wait on TestFlight. For example, You've uploaded a 1.0 build, status is `Pending Developer Release`. Change version build to 1.1 and upload again. When you release 1.0 version, and upgrade the current version to 1.1, you will see 1.1 is here to `Add for review`. Also, you need to wait again from `Waiting for review` -> `Reviewing` -> `Ready for sale`. There is no way to rollback.

Comment: On the App Store you will need to release 2.0.0 to the store before you can create 2.1.0

Comment: i mean that i want 2.0.0 and 2.1.0 are ready for sale at the same time, the first thing i do is to publish 2.0.0 (.NET MAUI), if it works as expected that's fine, but if it gets errors i will publish 2.1.0 (Native code) instead. is it possible to that in GG or Apple?

Comment: It may be easier to do a staged rollout of version 2.0.0 and stop it if you notice any problems

Comment: Yes you can upload it this way as long as the bundle identifier is the same